# aggrid inputs in table don't show the text when i try to filter in ipad or iphone devices

Tags: iphone, ipad, input, filter, ag-grid

When i try to filter in some column on some mobile devices like ipad or iphone, the inputs in aggrid don't show the text but they can filter anyway. I have noticed in my iphone and ipad with safari and chrome.

If you want to see this issue, you may enter the official website in 'demo' route with an iphone or ipad.

Comment: this is the official site example: https://www.ag-grid.com/example.php#/

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce your problem but there's not much point asking about it on Stack Overflow.

It's likely an ag-grid bug, you need to file an issue here:

https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/issues

Include this screenshot, or one like it:

[image]